# Angular $locationProvider html5Mode / <base> error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, html5-history, base-tag

So I'm running into a problem with Angular 1.3.15 and the $locationProvider. Every time I turn html5mode on I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` error. If I leave html5mode off, everything works fine.

My directory structure is like so (*4.DEV being a versioned directory name*):

```
public /
    - index.html
    4.DEV /
        css /
        js /
        images /
        partials /
        etc...
```

I have a base tag set like this:

```
<base href="/4.DEV/">
```

And I'm configuring the $locationProvider like so:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true });
```

If I change the base tag href to `"/"` Angular doesn't have any issues (but my assets don't load). I suspect that the issue Angular is having deals with the fact that my index.html file is one directory up from the rest of the site.

For reasons I won't list here, I can't change this dir structure and I REALLY don't want to change the base tag (because I don't want to manually stick a version number into all these files). I also want to leave html5mode on.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?  Is there any way for me to MANUALLY set the "base href" for Angular, but leave the tag alone for all my static assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it looks like Angular's inner workings are tightly coupled to the href of the  tag which results in major issues if you have a directory structure that's a bit unconventional like mine.

Stumbled across this [Github thread](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2805#issuecomment-19438128) where people are asking for a feature to change this and @greglockwood posted a fix.

With his fix, the  tag can work for your static assets while you provide your own set "baseHref" for Angular's stuff.

Worked like a charm for me!  Hope this helps anyone who stumbles across this!

Comment: Mate you saved me heaps of time!